# Using BufferedReader and FileReader; File is reading but not outputting its contents?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

I've written a program that should read an external file using the `BufferedReader` and `FileReader` classes. It recognizes the file and builds successfully, but it does not print out the contents of the text file in which it is supposed to do. Here is the code:

**Program**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab9 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String line;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a file name to read");

        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Lee\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Lab9\\" + sc.next()));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

            System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + "File was not found");        

            try { 
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException ex2) {
                System.out.println(ex2.getMessage() + "File did not read correctly");
            } finally {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The contents of the file that should be printed out look like this:

**File contents**

```
By what initials was Franklin Roosevelt better known?:FDR
Which number president was Franklin Roosevelt?:32
Which state was Franklin Roosevelt born in?:New York
In which year did Roosevelt become Governor of New York?:1929
What was the name of Franklin Roosevelt's wife?:Eleanor
How many children did Franklin Roosevelt have?:6
From which university did Franklin Roosevelt graduate with an A.B in history?:Harvard
What was the first name of Franklin Roosevelt's 5th cousin, who was also President?:Theodore
Which disease is believed to be the causes of Franklin Roosevelt's paralysis?:Polio
At what age did Franklin Roosevelt die?:63
```

**Actual output**

```
Please enter a file name to read
Questions.txt
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)
```

Any help on resolving this issue is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did this code compile ? Your first catch block did not close there. or is it typo ?

Comment: Hint: format all your code properly in an IDE, so that the indentation will help you. Then look at where your `while` loop is. I would suggest removing *all* your try/catch statements, and just declare that your `main` method can throw `IOException`...

Comment: I placed one of the brackets in the wrong place. After going through the indentation and formatting it properly I found the error, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have tried to read the file in the exception branch for the `FileNotFoundException`. This would mean, your program reads the file, only if it was not found, which makes no sense. It works like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String line;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter a file name to read: ");

    try {

        reader = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Lee\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Lab9\\" + sc.next()));

        try {

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                    ex.getMessage() + "File did not read correctly");
        } finally {
            try {
                if (reader != null)
                    reader.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("File was not found.");
    }

}
```

As a side note, you should always close the resources you use, in this case your file opened by `FileReader`, as seen above in the `finally` branch. Additionally, you do not need to call `System.exit(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

the first catch statement doesn't have end bracket so the file reader is inside the catch statement.

Answer (score 0):

you tried to read the file only when the `FileNotFoundException` was thrown. Also you should close resources after using them. what about this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String line;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a file name to read");

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Lee\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Lab9\\" + scanner.next()))) {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
        System.out.println(fileNotFoundException.getMessage() + ". File was not found");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String line;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a file name to read");
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    "C:\\Users\\Lee\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Lab9\\"
                            + sc.next()));
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
        }
```